# Read Dataset and grouping some informations with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I've a Dataset on a .tsv file structured like this:

```
user_000001 2009-05-04T23:08:57Z    f1b1cf71-bd35-4e99-8624-24a6e15f133a    Deep Dish       Fuck Me Im Famous (Pacha Ibiza)-09-28-2007
user_000001 2009-05-04T13:54:10Z    a7f7df4a-77d8-4f12-8acd-5c60c93f4de8    坂本龍一        Composition 0919 (Live_2009_4_15)
user_000002 2009-05-04T13:52:04Z    a7f7df4a-77d8-4f12-8acd-5c60c93f4de8    坂本龍一        Mc2 (Live_2009_4_15)
user_000002 2009-05-04T13:42:52Z    a7f7df4a-77d8-4f12-8acd-5c60c93f4de8    坂本龍一        Hibari (Live_2009_4_15)
```

This is a dataset of users who listen to music and the means of various columns is: user id, date-time when the user has listen a specific song, artis id, artis name, track id and track name.

Here the example how I read this dataset:

```
import io
import csv
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('lastfm-dataset-1K/fixed.tsv', sep='\t', error_bad_lines=False)
df.columns = ['user', 'date', 'artid', 'artname', 'trackid', 'trackname']
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
sessid = 0
# The new dataframe will have the following columns
newDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['sessid', 'user', 'trackid', 'count'])
```

So I want to create a "session" to know which songs each user has listened to every hour of every day.

The session is a simple incremental integer starting by 0 that rappresent a day an hour of listening (if is it complicated to slip a day for every hour I'm satisfy to group for each day).

The column count is to know how many times the user has listened a single song.

Can anyone explain me how can I do this? 
Thankyou

## Edit 1

As  Vivek Kalyanarangan suggested an expected response will be like:

```
SessionID, user, trackid; count
1, user_00001, id_song1, 1
1, user_00001, id_song2, 4
1, user_00001, id_song3, 2
# Different session id because of different user, but maybe he as listened the same songs (or not, just an example)
2, user_00002, id_song1, 2 
2, user_00002, id_song3, 1
```

## Edit 2

I said something wrong about the session.
A session of listening is a session where two different songs are heard in a time frame of less than an hour. So a session can be also only one song if the second is listened like 1:20 hour later.

Comment: please post an expected response that corresponds to your input

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not good with Pandas, so starting by the solution of @jezrael I propose my solution about your second edit.

```
datasetPath = ""
sessionPath = ""
resultPath = r""

# Use this function in order to calculate delta difference in hour
def delta(date1, date2):
    # 2006-08-13T13:59:20Z
    date1 = datetime.strptime(str(date1), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    date2 = datetime.strptime(str(date2), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    delta = date1 - date2
    totsec = delta.total_seconds()
    h = totsec/3600

    return h * (-1)

# Read the dataset 
df = pd.read_csv(datasetPath, sep='\t', error_bad_lines=False)
df.columns = ['user', 'date', 'artid', 'artname', 'trackid', 'trackname']

# Order by user and date
df = df.sort_values(by=['user', 'date'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
# Delete useless column
df = df.drop(['artid', 'artname','trackname'], axis=1)

# Get unique user id
id_users = df['user'].unique()

# Convert dataframe into numpy matrix in order to use for cycle
# user  date    trackid
np_matrix = df.as_matrix()
numrows = len(np_matrix) 

# Session start by one
session = 1
count = 0

out_file = open(sessionPath,"a")
out_file.write("session" + "\t" + "user" + "\t" + "trackid\n")

strings=[]

for user in id_users:

    print("Cicle user: " + str(user))
    while count < numrows:

        # Same user 
        if(user == np_matrix[count][0]):
            # Check about overflow
            if(count +1 < numrows):
                # Check delta, if delta < 1 is the same session. Else session++
                if( delta(np_matrix[count][1], np_matrix[count+1][1]) > 1.0):
                    session = session + 1
                else:
                    strings.append( (str(session) + "\t" + str(user) + "\t" + str(np_matrix[count][2])))


        count = count + 1

    session  = session + 1
    count = 0

for string in strings:
  out_file.write("%s\n" % string)

out_file.close()


# Count the same song in one session
df2 = pd.read_csv(sessionPath, sep='\t', error_bad_lines=False)
df2.columns = ['session', 'user', 'trackid']
df2 = df2.groupby(['session', 'user','trackid']).size().reset_index(name='count')
#print (df2)
df2.to_csv(resultPath, header=True, index=False, sep='\t', mode='w')
```

Sounds good?

Answer (score 1):

I believe need [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = df.sort_values('date')
df['sessid'] = pd.factorize(df['date'].dt.floor('H'))[0] + 1
df = df.groupby(['sessid', 'user','trackid']).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
   sessid         user            trackid  count
0       1  user_000001  Fuck Me Im Famous      1
1       2  user_000001   Composition 0919      1
2       2  user_000002             Hibari      1
3       2  user_000002                Mc2      1
```

**Details**:

First create `date` with `hour`s only by [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html):

```
print (df['date'].dt.floor('H'))
0   2009-05-04 23:00:00
1   2009-05-04 13:00:00
2   2009-05-04 13:00:00
3   2009-05-04 13:00:00
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Convert it to numeric by [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
print (pd.factorize(df['date'].dt.floor('H'))[0] + 1)
[1 2 2 2]
```

Comment: Ok, Now I'm trying some tests. I'll give it to you some feedback asap